# Getting error in publisher(_:didFailWithError:) -> 1541 - Timed out while attempting to publish

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, opentok

My App requirement is to test Audio and Video quality first, then start video call.
Network test is done properly.
And when I start actual call I'm getting above error. And unable to publish my feed and audio to subscriber.
I think issue might be in destroying audio, video session.

**publisher(_:didFailWithError:)**

**1541 - Timed out while attempting to publish.**

https://github.com/opentok/opentok-network-test/tree/master/iOS-Sample
If I don't use network test class my app works fine.

I've tried in opentok version 2.19.1, 2.20.0

Session Connection

```
func setupOpenTok() {
    guard
        let sessionID = sessionID,
        let token = token else {
        return
    }
    connectToAnOpenTokSession(withSessionID: sessionID, authToken: token)
}

func connectToAnOpenTokSession(withSessionID sessionID: String, authToken: String) {
    session = OTSession(apiKey: ADDConstants.OpenTOK.openTokAPIKey, sessionId: sessionID, delegate: self)
    guard let session = session else { return }
    session.connect(withToken: authToken, error: &error)
}

func sendPublisherView() {
    let settings = OTPublisherSettings()
    settings.name = UIDevice.current.name
    settings.videoTrack = isAppointmentTypeVideo
    if !isAppointmentTypeVideo {
        let myAudioDevice = OTDefaultAudioDevice()
        OTAudioDeviceManager.setAudioDevice(myAudioDevice)
    }
    guard let publisher = OTPublisher(delegate: self, settings: settings) else { return }
    var error: OTError?
    guard let session = session else { return }
    publisher.publishAudio = true
    publisher.publishVideo = isAppointmentTypeVideo

    session.publish(publisher, error: &error)
    self.publisher = publisher
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let publisherView = publisher.view else { return }
    publisherView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    publisherView.frame = publisherContainer.bounds
    publisherContainer.addSubview(publisherView)
}

func fetchSubscriberView() {
    print("fetchSubscriberView()")
    guard let stream = stream else { return }
    subscriber = OTSubscriber(stream: stream, delegate: self)
    subscriber?.subscribeToAudio = true
    subscriber?.subscribeToVideo = isAppointmentTypeVideo
    guard let subscriber = subscriber else { return }
    var error: OTError?
    guard let session = session else { return }
    session.subscribe(subscriber, error: &error)
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let subscriberView = subscriber.view else { return }
    subscriberView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    view.insertSubview(subscriberView, at: 0)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(publisherContainer)
}
```

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your code. You can try unpublishing https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTSession.html#//api/name/unpublish:error:

Comment: Network test code is same us below demo.
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-network-test/tree/master/iOS-Sample

Comment: @abdulajet I've updated the code

Comment: Did you try unpublishing? Maybe the network test code didn't tear down correctly

Comment: are you using the same session for network test and for calling?

Comment: Yes I tried unpublishing.
and using different sessions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234654/discussion-between-abdulajet-and-anis-mansuri).

Comment: did you find any solution?